# react history push appends to url instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to redirect my user to the detail page when he successfully creates an object from my list page. Here is my code:

**history.js**

```
import {createHashHistory} from 'history';
const history = createHashHistory();   
export default history
```

**app.js**

```
    class App extends Component {

  render() {    

        return (
          <Router history={history}>
            <Alerts/>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Main}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )

  }
}
```

**SAGA**

```
export function* workerCreateTicket(action) {
...
...
yield call(forwardTo, `/tickets/${data.data.id}`); //<--- function to redirect if successful
...
}

function forwardTo(location) {
history.push(location);
}
```

**Expected**

I expected the URL to be as such:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/tickets/14
```

**result**
however i received this instead

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/tickets#/tickets/14
```

Comment: You are using `createHashHistory`, it is default behavior to add URL as hash for it

Answer (score 0):

It is about `createHashHistory`. You use `hash-history`, it means `history`-lib handle only part of url **after** hash (#).

You can switch it to `createBrowserHistory`, it handle **whole** url.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. By using browserhistory , how would i handle for manual url entering and refreshes?

Comment: You must setup your server for passing **any** route to `index.html` and after that, `react-router` handle it on the client-side.

Comment: Do you have an example that i can reference? Im abit new to this

Comment: Are you using `nginx` as a server?

Comment: Im using django dev server, but i plan to use nginx as a proxy with gunicorn as my wsgi and daphne as the asgi

Comment: In `nginx` you can simple add the following snippet to you `server`-section: `location / { try_files $uri /index.html; }`. It tries to find file with requested url, if it fails — server send `index.html` page.

This is nice `nginx` config generator — https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx

Comment: But I have no idea, how setup django dev-server for this situation, sorry.

Comment: Okay , meanwhile is it possible to use HashRouter to use an absolute path instead of appending to the end of the url?

Comment: Yep, sure. But original path must include `hash` to. E.g. if you have route `http://127.0.0.1:3000#tickets` and dispatch your action, you receive `http://127.0.0.1:3000#tickets/14`. You can't mix `hash` and **normal** routing. Choose one.

Answer (score 0):

can you try pass a attribute (history) with your action when call in container.
=> workerCreateTicket(action)
const { history } = action;